# Using python to do a calculation on a set of numbers in a text field separated by commas

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, python-script-tool

Using ArcGIS ArcMap 10.6:

I have a text field in an attribute table that has comma separated values (example: 12,24, 64, 87,29 OR 13, 45, 32,21,34, 45). For this example, I will name this field `VALUES`. Please note that `VALUES` includes data collected from field work so the spacing between commas will be varied. My goal is to be able to run a calculation on each number before the comma, and to get the sum of that number in a new field called `Calculated_Values`.

Though, I am currently using excel, as I cannot figure out how to do this with python. My current workflow is as followed:

1. Export the `ID` and `VALUES` fields in the attribute table into a .csv file using Table to Table in ArcMap 10.6
2. Open the .csv in Excel and run the 'text to columns' function under the Data ribbon
3. Separate the `VALUES` field into multiple columns based on commas
4. Run this calculation: =ROUND(SQRT(POWER(A2,2)+POWER(B2,2)+POWER(C2,2)+POWER(D2,2)+POWER(E2,2)+POWER(F2,2)+POWER(G2,2)+POWER(H2,2)),0) in `Column I`
5. Copy `Column I` values and `ID` columns into a new .csv file
6. Save and close the new .csv file and join the shapefile to the new .csv file based on `ID`
7. Export the newly joined shapefile into a new file and delete the duplicate `ID` field in the new shapefile

I am wondering if there is a way to automate this Python/ArcPy so I can create a custom script tool to do this without leaving the ArcGIS environment.

**Is there a way to separate values in a text field based on commas into different columns, run the above calculation, and have the values from that calculation entered in a new field named** `VALUES_CALCULATED`?

I know I have to use a cursor but don't know what type of for loop to run in it.